# iOS console application to be runned by launchd

Tags: ios, xcode, jailbreak, launchd, launch-daemon

Does anyone has some tips on creating a console tool in Xcode for iOS. I want to run it via launchd and it should send request to a server.

But I can´t find any way to compile a "application" without UI in Xcode for ARM.

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22516685/119114), that installing iOSOpenDev is usually the right way to solve this problem.  Once it's installed, it adds new templates to Xcode.  You can then add a new target to your project with **File** -> **New** -> **Target...**.  Choose from an *iOSOpenDev* template, the one named *Command-line Tool*.

However, if this isn't an option, or you want to know how to do it another way, it's not too difficult.

Simply create a new Xcode Project.  For the project type, start with the simplest one ... probably an **iOS** -> **Application** -> **Single View Application**.

Once the project is created, simply delete any View, ViewController, or .xib files, as you won't use them.  In your list of Frameworks (Project Settings -> Build Phases), you can delete UIKit.framework, or anything else a non-graphical tool doesn't need.

Then, simply go into the generated main.m file, and remove its call to `UIApplicationMain()`.  Instead, I usually create a main daemon class, and then start it with something like this, from main.m:

```
#import "HelloDaemon.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   @autoreleasepool {
      HelloDaemon* daemon = [[HelloDaemon alloc] init];
      
      // start a timer so that the process does not exit.
      NSTimer* timer = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate: [NSDate date]
                                                interval: 1.0
                                                  target: daemon
                                                selector: @selector(run:)
                                                userInfo: nil
                                                 repeats: NO];
      
      NSRunLoop* runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
      [runLoop addTimer: timer forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
      [runLoop run];
   }
   
   return 0;
}
```

where my daemon class contains a `run:` method:

```
-(void) run:(NSTimer *) timer;
```

When you build this "app" for an iOS Device (not the simulator!), it will stick it in a build output directory, such as:

```
./Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/HelloDaemon.app/HelloDaemon
```

The executable is the `HelloDaemon` file under the .app directory.  Copy that to your iPhone, and use it from the command-line, as a launch daemon, or however else you'd like.

### References

[Chris Alvares' old, but good tutorial on launch daemons](https://www.chrisalvares.com/blog/7/creating-an-iphone-daemon-part-1/)

Answer (score 1):

[iOSOpenDev](http://www.iosopendev.com) Provides exactly what you are described.